# How to say "Custom order is available" in Japanese?

Tags: english-to-japanese

Can I say "Custom order for XXX is available. I am currently living in YYY. If you wish to order, please visit the following website." as the follows?

XXXカスタマーオーダーOK！私は今YYに住んでいます。ご注文をご希望の場合は、以下のウェブサイトをご覧ください。

Thank you very much if someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Custom order can be said as 「カスタムメイド」 or I have also heard 「オーダーメイド」(made-to-order).

"I am currently living here" is fine as is.

Visiting a website is frequently said as 「アクセスする」

Full translation:

> XXX様のオーダーメイド注文OK。今、私はYYに住んでいます。ご注文をご希望の場合は、以下のウェブサイトにアクセスしてください。

Or perhaps you could say it like this - a little formal.

> XXX様のオーダーメイド注文は完成です。私の現在の住まいはYYです。ご注文をご希望の場合は、以下のウェブサイトにアクセスしてください。

Comment: XXXのところは商品名じゃないんですかね。。　お客さんの名前じゃなくて・・